# How to execute a PHP script upon SweetAlert2 confirmation?

Tags: javascript, php, function, sweetalert

I use Sweet Alert 2 for nice dialogs.

Now, I want to use it for a security question of whether a database entry should be deleted.
It's no problem to show the dialogue, but I can't find a way to integrate a function if the delete is confirmed.

That is the code for now:

```
    <script>
        Swal.fire({
            title: '',
            text: "Diesen Eintrag wirklich löschen?",
            icon: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: 'Ja',
            cancelButtonText: 'Nein',
            reverseButtons: true
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                Swal.fire(
                '<Here a function if delete is confirmed>'
                )
            } else {
                Swal.fire(
                '<Here a function to go back>'
                )
            }
        })
    </script>
    
    <?php
    public function deleteConfimred(){
        // Delete the entry
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could submit a form using JS which submits to the PHP file where your function is.

HTML:

```
<form id="yourFormId" action="yourphpfile.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="">
</form>
<button type="button" onclick="confirmDelete()">Delete</button>

<script>
function confirmDelete() {
    Swal.fire({
        title: '',
        text: "Diesen Eintrag wirklich löschen?",
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'Ja',
        cancelButtonText: 'Nein',
        reverseButtons: true
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
            document.getElementById("yourFormId").submit();
        }
    })
}
</script>
```

yourphpfile.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
 deleteConfirmed();
}

public function deleteConfirmed(){
    // Delete the entry
}
?>
```